# Django & Apache: How to debug on Testing server

Tags: django, debugging, apache2

I am trying to debug an issue that happens on our testing server. So how do I make it so that I can access our testing server when I start Django by typing:

`python manage.py runserver`

?

Does it have to pass through Apache? If so, I need to configure Apache somehow but I am not using mod_wsgi and so, don't know how to do this.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the test server runs its own web server. the defaul options starts a server on
 http://127.0.0.1:8000/, which you can then open in your browser

you can specify an optional ip address/server using

```
manage.py runserver ip:port
```

using ip 0.0.0.0 for all network interfaces

Comment: But when I go to the url:8000 all I get is:

Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at <IP ADDRESS REMOVED>:8000.

Comment: Doing `manage.py runserver ip:port` worked as expected! :)  Thanks.

Comment: if the server is running on localhost (127.0.0.1) you can only access it using that ip, from the same computer. to access externally you need to specify the external ip, and for both, 0.0.0.0 is handy. (or if you just can't remember the ip)